# Javascript doesn't work on ajax generated code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, iframe, file-upload

I'm using [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) to upload files. The plugin uses a hidden iframe to

upload without refreshing the page. Everything works fine except javascript doesn't work on

generated code. Here's my code:

```
    <form id="image_form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" id="image_file" name="image_file"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="upload">
    </form>
    <div id="avatar_wrapper">
    </div>
```

This form uploads an image to server and server will return some processed images.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            success: showResponse,
            dataType: 'html'
        };
    $('#image_form').ajaxForm(options);

        $('.choose_avatar').hover(function() { /* Just for test */
            alert('hello');
        });
    });
    function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        $('#avatar_wrapper').append(responseText);
    }
</script>
```

responseText contains some images.

```
  <img src="http://localhost/avatar/0.jpg" class="choose_avatar" choice=0>
  <img src="http://localhost/avatar/1.jpg" class="choose_avatar" choice=1>
  <img src="http://localhost/avatar/2.jpg" class="choose_avatar" choice=2>
```

I wrote these code to test:

```
$('.choose_avatar').click(function() { /* Just for test */
    alert('hello');
});
```

It's strange that click function doesn't work on these generated code.
Can someone please help me with this?Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to use `live()`, or do it manually, place a `click` handler on the parent element that is constant, and check `event.target` to see which one was clicked.

This is how `live` works under the hood, anyway, so just stick with it :)

Note that if you're using a newer jQuery, then use `on()` instead of `live()`.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use [**`.live`**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) on these dynamically generated elements.

```
$('.choose_avatar').live("click", function() { /* Just for test */
    alert('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On the container avatar_wrapper you must bind a live/delegate listener :

```
$('#avatar_wrapper').delegate('.choose_avatar','click',function() {
    alert('hello');
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `$('.choose_avatar')`, you are selecting elements with class `choose_avatar` (which don't exist yet) and attaching the event handler. Which obviously won't work if the elements are loaded dynamically. A more correct approach is to handle the delegated event on the wrapper div like so,

```
$('#avatar_wrapper').delegate('img.choose_avatar', 'click', function (e) {
    // do stuff
});
```